# If there's anything I need to add to this proof, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm doing a proof for the following statement:

Z (defined as the set of real numbers belonging to all inductive sets of real numbers) is the smallest inductive set of reals in the sense that Z is a subset of I  folds for all inductive sets I.

Here's the proof I constructed:

Proof: We need a way to show how Z being a subset of I is a subset for all inductive sets I. Therefore, we need to prove first that if an element x is in Z, then x is in I. Let x be in Z. Then x is a real number such that it belongs to all inductive sets of real numbers. Since x belongs to all inductive sets of real numbers x belongs to I.

Any additional thoughts would be helpful!

Comment: You should change your title to be more descriptive and add the tag "solution verification". I would edit it but I'm on my phone so it's hard to.

Comment: Have you already shown that Z is an inductive set? It can't be the smallest inductive set if it isn't an inductive set itself!

Comment: You only prove the "easy" part of the question - obviously if $Z$ is the intersection of a collection of sets, then $Z$ is a subset of any set in the collection.  You need to show that $Z$ is itself an inductive set.